# Report - Count number of non-empty records in a row

Tags: reporting, formula

I'm dealing with quite simple thing. I need to count number of non-empty records in a row. As a result of a formula I want to have a percentage of email addresses in my Contacts. I'm using Salesforce Professional.

Comment: Non-empty records? Or do you mean non-empty columns/fields in a record/row? So basically do you want to know how many contacts have an email address, and how many don't, by running a report?

Comment: Exactly, I need to create a pie chart in dashboard afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Create a text formula field on Contact called something like 'Has Email Address'. The formula will be

```
IF(ISBLANK(Email), "No", "Yes")
```

You can use this field for filtering and grouping in your reports.

Comment: Could also be a formula checkbox field.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a report for this.  On this report, create a formula that basically checks to see if there is a value in the email field or not.  If it does, set it to one value and another if it doesn't.  Have your report then group by this field.  That should do the trick.

You can then create a dashboard off of this report afterwards.